# What ios application uses a user-agent containing `GmmClient:google_ios`?

Tags: user-agent

I've seen in the logs of my site the following user agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 12.4.1; en_US; ) AppleWebKit/0.0 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/0.0; GmmClient:google_ios/com.google.Maps/5.27.8/Mobile/ios:iPhone10,3/iOS-AppStore
```

What app can be generating this traffic?

Answer (score 0):

The part `GmmClient:google_ios/com.google.Maps/5.27.8/Mobile/ios` probably indicates that traffic is generated from  Google Maps for iOS, when THe website is opened in a webview inside this app.

But I can't find any documentation referencing `GmmClient` so I can't confirm it.